# How did part of my house in minecraft disappear?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I was playing Minecraft 1.6.2 survival mode (normal difficulty), and I built a house. Then I went far away to explore a cave. When I got back, part of my house had simply disappeared.

[image: Screenshot showing part of house missing]

As you can see, a part of my house just vanished. There used to be walls and a roof, but not anymore.

[image: Screenshot showing part of house missing looking from above]

The stranger thing is, the wooden floor just turned into a perfect square of dirt.

[image: Screenshot showing where floor used to be]

There also used to be a pond nearby, but part of the pond also turned into dirt. (as indicated by the redstone circuit.)

[image: Screenshot showing where pond used to be]

Fences are gone. My iron golem and a cat are nowhere to be found.
The whole area encircled by the redstone simply turn into dirt.

I thought of a creeper explosion. Yes, I might have left the gate open, and yes a creeper might be able to sneak into the house, (if it managed to get pass my two cats).
It seems unlikely that an explosion would occur. There is no hole on the ground, and the roof is gone too. I don't think the blast radius is that large. The house was fine when I left. Doesn't a creeper has to be near me to trigger an explosion?

I am really puzzled. Can somebody explain what happened? I would be very grateful.

Comment: Creepers only damage an area of roughly 6*6 blocks, at least on sand. Different blocks resist explosions differently, for example, a creeper exploding on sand will cause more destruction than if it exploded on dirt.

Comment: Did you have any chests in that chunk? That would suck

Comment: @Cruncher Fortunately no. _shudder_

Comment: "Aliens took part of my house!"

Comment: Ouch, I know that bug well. I once built a whole village on a server, and one day the server crashed and blit away half of it in random chunks :(

Comment: I don't think the pond was replaced. I was covered as you can see a bit of water.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

It most certainly was no creeper, creepers don't place dirt back.

It looks like chunk got reset. The minecraft world is infinite, but is internally stored in 16x16 "chunks" of land. The chunks you explored are saved to a file (so the more land you explore, the bigger your save file becomes), if this file gets lost, the game will regenerate the area and basically "reset" the land back to what it was before any player made modifications and without any items/entities(your cat and golem are entities). Another way a chunk could get reset is if a bug caused the game to think "this chunk doesn't exist yet", and then the game will regenerate the area.

The area that got reset in your case is a 16x16 block area (or a multiple of that, can't see if there are any other strange borders further out to the top of your picture).

If you had any mining shaft running through that area, they'll be refilled with stone too. The good part is that ores are replaced too! So if you remember finding diamonds right under that piece of land, they'll be replaced too!

Comment: Thank you!! But why would a chunk reset itself? Is there anything i can do to prevent this from happening?

Comment: I doubt there is a way to prevent it. Only thing I can think of is backing up your saves at times, but if I understood Arperum's answer correctly, that could possibly just copy the imminent chunk reset anyway.

Comment: Not much you can do, I think I've had it happen once since I play minecraft, and I've been playing since late alpha (2010)

Comment: The only time this happened to me, it was because of a mod I was using that was buggy and inhibited proper saving.

Comment: "by 16 wide and 16 high" I believe you mean "a 16 by 16 area". The height of a chunk is from bedrock to sky. So their height is 256

Comment: yup, 16x16 area. I couldn't find the word to point the top/bottom direction of the picture

Comment: I like to think that it was a once-in-a-lifetime coordination of Endermen.  The Endermen strike force.

Comment: @JeffGohlke I'm intrigued now. If you just let minecraft run forever, will endermen eventually build a kickass castle because of the infinite monkey theorem?

Comment: @Cruncher a dirt castle then, because they can't move stone.

Comment: @Arperum Was that updated at some point? I could swear that they used to be able to.

Comment: @Cruncher Yeah, they can only pick up stuff that appears on the surface now. It was pretty broken before...

Comment: Sometimes if a chunk becomes corrupted in a save, Mincraft will "fix" it by regenerating it. That's often the cause of chunk resets.

Answer (score 13):

In your world go to the point of the map that has reset (easier in create) and press F3.
This will tell you your x, y and z point.
If your not in create mode and have cheats enabled write /gamemode 1.
If your not in create mode and have cheats disabled pause the game click open to lan, turn on allow cheats, click start lan world and then write /gamemode 1.

[image: xyz]

It doesn't matter what it says after the decimal point.

Once you get your x, y and z coordinates go to this website https://dinnerbone.com/minecraft/tools/coordinates/
and type your coordinates in the Block Information Section. Y does not matter because you are measuring in chunks. 
In the Region Information Section it tells you the filename.
[image: Coordinates]

When you found out the file name press the windows key and R
[image: Keyboard]

This brings up run

[image]

Type ***%appdata%*** as seen in the picture and press ok. this brings up the appdata folder.
Go to appdata/roaming/.minecraft/saves/*NAME OF YOUR WORLD*/region and find the file that https://dinnerbone.com/minecraft/tools/coordinates/ told you the name of.

[image]
Rename the file as shown. mine was r.-1.-1.mca but some of my stuff was not gone and I had to copy this stuff to another chunk temporarily using the /clone command. I made two more backups. Those parts of the map were recreated. The backups were because I copied over 40,000 blocks and I was not going through the effort of deleting it all. So i just renamed two files and those parts of the map were recreated.

I had to copy my stuff, fix the corrupted chunk, copy my stuff back to its original place and then create the other two backups.

This set me back about an hour and a half but even though I had to start some of my house again I was happy I fixed the map and did not have to start all over again.

Doing this you cannot get all of your stuff e.g. If you had a castle and half of it got deleted you can fix the corrupted chunk but you cannot get the other half of the castle back.

Answer (score -2):

Your house must of been reset somehow. A creeper would have blown up the ground and more of your house in different places, not just the walls. Also, Creepers cannot replace blocks (e.g. Water with Grass blocks).

Comment: So why was the house reset?