# How do I get the other half of my house back?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Half my house disappeared in Minecraft. I tried to update from 1.5.2 to 1.8, but it didn't work. So I went back to 1.5.2, and spawned at the beginning where I spawned when I created the world. I went to look if my house was still there and it was. Half. I thought it was a glitch and it had to generate. but when I came closer it was half gone. My farm, my chests, my mine,... 
[image: Screenshot showing partial house]

Comment: Do you have a picture of how it looks now? [this question](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/173133/how-did-part-of-my-house-in-minecraft-disappear) might be related. (not enough information to know if duplicate or not.

Comment: ALWAYS MAKE BACKUPS WHEN UPDATE MINECRAFT !!!

Comment: Looks like your map got corrupted and the game recreated the chunk.

Comment: possible duplicate: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/173133/how-did-part-of-my-house-in-minecraft-disappear?lq=1

Answer (score 4):

In Minecraft 1.8 there are more blocks than 1.5.2. So when you construct the house in 1.8, and go back to 1.5.2, all 1.5.2+ blocks and items will be lost. Nothing to do about it but next time make a back up!

Comment: "I tried to update from 1.5.2 to 1.8, but it didn't work. So I went back to 1.5.2"